# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to query my db but keep getting a fatal error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in G:\xampp\htdocs\login&register\New_folder\classes\connect.php:78 Stack trace: #0 G:\xampp\htdocs\login&register\New_folder\classes\connect.php(78): PDOStatement->execute() #1 G:\xampp\htdocs\login&register\New_folder\core\init.php(14): db->query('SELECT `usernam...', Array) #2 G:\xampp\htdocs\login&register\New_folder\login.php(3): require('G:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in G:\xampp\htdocs\login®ister\New_folder\classes\connect.php on line 78

Can someone please help cause i have read tons of solutions regarding this problem but none seems to work.

CONNECT.PHP

```
class db{
    private 
        $_host = 'localhost',
        $_dbname = 'mydb',
        $_username = 'root',
        $_password = 'adoloveado',
        $_pdo = NULL,
        $_query,
        $_count = 0,
        $_error = true;

private static $_instance = NULL;

private function __construct(){

    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host = {$this->_host}; dbname = {$this->_dbname}", $this->_username, $this->_password);
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if($this->_pdo){
            echo "Connected to ". strtoupper($this->_dbname) ." database successfully ...<br/>";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($this->_error ? $e->getMessage() : " ");
    }
}

    public function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new db();
    }
        return self::$_instance;
}



public function query($sql, $params = array() ){
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            echo "Success";
         }
      }
  }
}
```

INIT.PHP

```
<?php 

require('classes/connect.php');

db::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? OR username = ?", array(

    'pingo','billy'

));
```

Comment: Just a thought, maybe you should take the spaces out of your PDO initialization string

Comment: It's definitely the spaces.

Comment: Start by changing it to `"mysql:host={$this->_host};dbname={$this->_dbname}"` then tell us if you're still having problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes it was the spacing ... :)

Comment: You're welcome. The question has been closed based on the same error.